# how can i retrieve and save latitiude and longitude from django-mapbox-LocationField?

Tags: django, django-models, mapbox, geodjango

i careate a django models with mapbox-locationfield :

```
from mapbox_location_field.models import LocationField

class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,blank=True,null=True)
      location = LocationField(null=True, blank=True)
      latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=18,null=True, blank=True)
      longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=18,null=True, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.store_name

      def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
          if self.location:
             self.latitude = self.location.y
             self.longitude = self.location.x
          super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

i want to save latitude and longitude but i got this error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'y'

Answer (score 1):

The specified .x / .y functions are imported from `mapbox_location_field.models` but you can't run the code because these functions are not in the models file. So the `LocationField` class doesn't have the function that you want. You can check the source code at the link [here](https://github.com/simon-the-shark/django-mapbox-location-field/blob/master/mapbox_location_field/models.py).

If you want to use these functions, you can access them from folders such as `point.py` , `linestring.py` in the `django.contrib.gis.geos` directory. For more details, [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/gis/geos).

You can try this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(blank = True, null=True)
    
    def longitude(self):
        return self.location.x

    def latitude(self):
        return self.location.y
```